# Jade extends does not work

Tags: express, pug

I have an issue on `extends` on jade template. I am building simple todo list web app and have two jade files, layout.jade and login.jade.

```
//layout.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
  body
    h1 Welcomt to Todo list
    block content

//login.jade
extends ./layout.jade

block content
form(action='form_receiver' method='post')
  p
    input(type='text' name='name')
  p
    textarea(name='description')
  p
    input(type='submit' name='submission')
```

I used `includes` instead of block, then it works for me but if I use `extends` and `block contents`, it does not work.
Did I miss something on here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you extend from layout.jade you have to declare the content in the extensions in layout.jade. You do that correctly by defining `block content` and including the `block content` in login.jade. However, Jade is built on indentation. Your form is not inside the block content and therefore nothing is being shown.
Just indent the form and it will work.

```
block content
  form(action='form_receiver' method='post')
    p
      input(type='text' name='name')
    p
      textarea(name='description')
    p
      input(type='submit' name='submission')
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed small thing and it changes everthing!

Comment: I just fixed indention of login.jade(child jade file) but, still no luck. hm

Comment: Weird. I run the exact same code as you now and it works for me. Sure you have the same code here as you do in your text editor? Haven't spelled anything wrong there?

Comment: Yes I do. I just copied, pasted and had 4 spaces for each lines.

Comment: not even error message. Do I have problem on layout file?

Comment: No. Not that I can see, as long as everything in you file is exactly like it is here. Like I said. Exact same thing works for me. Maybe something in your express setup.

Comment: If it is because my express setup, do you know why it works when I use `include` instead of `extends`?

Comment: Well. If you are telling express to render layout.jade it would work with an include but not with an extend. And possibly other scenarios as well.

Comment: I did not know that. I actually used `res.render('layout');`. How is  your express setting?

Comment: You need to res.render('login'). Because in login.jade you are stating that it is extending layout.jade. However, in layout.jade there is no information telling the server to use login.jade. That is the whole idea about extending. Based on which url you are requesting you want to change the block content, but you always want the layout.jade to be included.

Comment: Wow. I totally didnt know that and appreciate your advice!! I cannot do right now, but I will let you know as I try it out!